# PHP Code Within PHP Include

Tags: php, include, echo

I'm creating a php page and I'm using `include` statements to load the contents but it's having a bad effect on the output.  Here are my files:

index.php:

```
<div class="sectionSpacer"></div>
<?php include("newsection.php"); ?>
<div class="sectionSpacer"></div>
```

newsection.php:

```
<div class="sectionInner">
    <div id="details">
        <?php echo $details; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

$details:

```
My email address is <?php echo $my_email; ?>
```

The problem is that while the div is being displayed, `$details` isn't echoing out the email address on the index page.  How can this be resolved?

Comment: Where is $details assigned a value?

Comment: Where is $my_email defined?

Comment: @Drakes It is defined at the top of my `index.php` page

Comment: As long as it is defined, my answer should display your email address

Answer (score 2):

Modify ur newsection.PHP to following:

```
<?php

$txt= <<< EOPAGE
<div class="sectionInner">
<div id="details">
    $details
</div>
</div>
 EOPAGE;

echo $txt;
?>
```

The declaration of variables details and my_mail:

```
   $my_email= "some.email@example. com;
   $details="My email address is". $my_email;
```

I am sure this will work

Answer (score 1):

In the case you are trying to echo the string `$details` of mixed HTML/PHP (like from a database), you can echo it this way:

```
echo eval(' ?>'.$details.'<?php ');
```

Then change your code to this:

```
<div class="sectionInner">
    <div id="details">
        <?php echo eval(' ?>'.$details.'<?php '); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course if you can rework your setup to avoid eval'ing PHP code, please, please do that.

Comment: How did this work out for you? Were you able to try it with your code and verify that it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do cannot be done, and you should know this if you understand how code is executed. put -myemail- into

```
$variable = "my email is -myemail-";
$variable = str_replace($variable,"-myemail-",$myemail);
echo $variable;
```

Comment: Ok, What about if the echoed `$details` contains a `<?php ?>` statement.  That's what isn't showing up - how can this be corrected?

Comment: try escaping it, that is a weird case.

Comment: Take a look at my updated question! How do I escape?

Comment: I'm sorry but can you show how that would work on my original post code?

Comment: I'm sorry but that doesn't really make sense to me.  `$details` IS being echoed but the `email` isn't, as stated in my question.

Comment: wait if you can assign to $details you are withing a <?php why are you now adding another one?

Comment: Because my $details statement is held within a database - I just want to echo out my email address.  How can I do this - Please read my question carefully - It clearly shows what I'm trying to acheive.

Comment: @JoshuaByer He's just trying to eval the $details string from his DB.